# Checking if a variable is set or not in a form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm able to check if a variable is set or not for a header as follows :

```
@if (isset($var1))
     <header><h3>"{{$var1}}" </h3></header>
@endif
```

But I don't know how to do the same for this form :

```
<form action="{{route('post.create',['var' => $var])}}" method="post">
```

as I'm receiving the following error :

```
Undefined variable: var
```

Comment: Post your controller method to render the view, please.

Comment: Added the controller code

Comment: Why can't you do the same if check for the `<form` (with an accompanying else)?

Comment: Can u give a simple example on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a form in laravel 5.2 you need to follow this approach

```
echo Form::open(array('route' => array('post.create', $var)))
```

This post will be lot of help to you https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html